# Calculate the amount of savings I will have in n months

Tags: java

I have the following problem and I am new in Java:

I have an initial capital of 10 000. I invest this initial capital of 10 000 in the bank for a interest rate per month of 0.04/12. My net income is 3000 per month and my expenses per month is 2000. I invest also my monthysavings = net income - expenses = 3000 - 2000 = 1000 in the bank for the interest rate of 0.04/12.

I would like to calculate the amount of savings I will have in 300 months.

I did the following code:

> ```
> public class RetCalcJava {
>
>
> public double futureCapital(
>       double interestRate
>     , int nbOfMonths
>     , int netIncome
>     , int currentExpenses
>     , double initialCapital) {
>
>
> double  monthlySavings = netIncome - currentExpenses;
> double iniVal=0;
> double finalVal =0;
> double intermediate = 0;
>
> for (int i=0; i< nbOfMonths; i++){
>     System.out.println("Boucle" + i);
>
>     if (i ==0) {
>         iniVal = initialCapital * (1 + interestRate) + monthlySavings;
>         intermediate = iniVal;
>
>         System.out.println("intival" + iniVal);
>     }
>     else {
>         finalVal =  intermediate * (1 + interestRate) + monthlySavings;
>         intermediate = finalVal;
>         System.out.println("finalVal" + finalVal);
>     } }    return finalVal;
> ```
>
> }
> }

The main class is :

```
public class RetCalcMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RetCalcJava retcal = new RetCalcJava();    
    retcal.futureCapital(0.04/12, 300, 3000,2000,10000);


    }
}
```

This code works. What do you think about my code? Is it optimized? What should I change?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Code Review. Few suggestions:

- **Formatting**: the code should be formatted to make it easier to read. Many IDEs support auto-formatting, or you can use an [online formatter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm).
- **Naming**: the class name `RetCalcJava` shouldn't include Java as suffix, the extension .java already tells what type of file is. It's also hard to understand what a class called `RetCalc` does, consider a more meaningful name. I am not sure what `Boucle` means.
- **Typo and spacing**: `iniVal`, `println("intival" + iniVal)`. There are some typos and the result of the print is "intival1000", it needs a space.
- **Static method**: The method `futureCapital` does not need to use instance variables, so it can be `static`. By making it `static` we don't need to instantiate the class.
- **Formatting the output**: the capital can be formatted as `541,267.20` instead of `541267.1989622512` using `System.out.printf` and `%,.2f`.
- **Accumulation**:

  ```
  iniVal = initialCapital * (1 + interestRate) + monthlySavings;
  intermediate = iniVal;
  System.out.println("intival" + iniVal);
  for (int i = 1; i < nbOfMonths; i++) {
      //...
      finalVal = intermediate * (1 + interestRate) + monthlySavings;
      intermediate = finalVal;
      // ...
  }
  return finalVal;
  ```

  The temporary variables `intermediate` and `initVal` are not necessary, see the code below.

### Revised code

```
public class RetCalc {
    public static double futureCapital(double interestRate, int months, int netIncome, int currentExpenses,
            double initialCapital) {
        double monthlySavings = netIncome - currentExpenses;
        double capital = initialCapital;
        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++) {
            capital = capital * (1 + interestRate) + monthlySavings;
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.printf("Initial value: %,.2f%n", capital);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Month: %d Capital: %,.2f%n", i + 1, capital);
            }
        }
        return capital;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double futureCapital = RetCalc.futureCapital(0.04 / 12, 300, 3000, 2000, 10000);
        System.out.printf("Future capital: %,.2f%n", futureCapital);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial value: 11,033.33
Month: 2 Capital: 12,070.11
...
Month: 300 Capital: 541,267.20
Future capital: 541,267.20
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public double futureCapital(
>       double interestRate
>     , int nbOfMonths
>     , int netIncome
>     , int currentExpenses
>     , double initialCapital) {
> ```

The idea behind the comma-first list separation is that it allows elements to be added to the end of the list without having to modify the current last item in the list.  This produces fewer changes in source control.

The problem is that, as you have implemented it, you have thrown away that advantage.  Because you have put `) {` on the last line.  So you are going to have to keep moving it if you were to add a new entry.  If so, you might as well write in one of the more readable styles:

```
public double futureCapital(
      double interestRate,
      int nbOfMonths,
      int netIncome,
      int currentExpenses,
      double initialCapital) {
```

or (more common in Java)

```
public double futureCapital(double interestRate, int nbOfMonths, int netIncome,
        int currentExpenses, double initialCapital) {
```

You also name a variable `nbOfMonths`.  What's an nb?  I'm guessing it's an abbreviation of number.  Contrast that with `monthCount`, which has the same number of characters but no abbreviations.

I also prefer to name scalars (like `int` or `double`) with singular names and use plural names for arrays and collections.  I.e. things over which I can iterate.

In general, methods should have verb names.  They do things.  In this case, I would start with `calculate`.  You could name the class something like `FutureCapital` or `ProjectedCapital`.

Given that your class has no object properties, I would make the method static.

Consider separating your output from your calculations.  E.g. return an array of `balances` and then display those.  That will make your program easier to modify in the future.

Comment: +1 for the comma-first list separation, I didn't know that. And for mentioning to use verbs in method names, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 2):

```java
    , int nbOfMonths
```

Don't shorten names just because you can. It does make the code harder to read, understand and maintain in the long run. Even when variable names become longer, make them as descriptive as possible.

---

```java
double  monthlySavings = netIncome - currentExpenses;
```

Don't use `double` or even `float` for money, it will come back to bite you. As it is with floating point numbers, they *will* have rounding errors which might or might not be a problem, but in my experience they always become one.

Either use `int`/`long` with the smallest unit your currency has (like Cents), or use a `BigDecimal` with an appropriate `MathContext` to get accurate results.

---

```java
for (int i=0; i< nbOfMonths; i++){
```

I'm a persistent opponent of single-letter variable names. In my opinion, you're only allowed to use single-letter variable names if you're dealing with dimensions. In this case, `i` could be `counter`, `monthCounter`.

---

You could get much more descriptive, but also a lot more verbose and complex, by using a builder-pattern like mechanic. Assume the following class:

```java
public class ReturnCalculator {
    protected BigDecimal capital;
    protected BigDecimal monthlyExpenses;
    protected BigDecimal monthlyNetIncome;
    protected int numberOfMonths;
    protected BigDecimal yearlyInterestRate;
```

Now, with that in place we are adding setters for every variable, like this one:

```java
public ReturnCalculator setCapital(BigDecimal capital) {
    this.capital = capital;
    
    return this;
}
```

Last but for sure not least, we add checks to the `calculateFutureCapital` method, like this:

```java
public BigDecimal calculateFutureCapital() {
    if (capital == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"capital\" is not set.");
    }
    // Repeat for every field.
    
    // return calculated value.
}
```

We could also assume "sane" defaults for the values, but that is rather not transparent in this case, so we'd do better with the checks which throw if something is wrong.

So, with that in place, we can use the class like this:

```java
BigDecimal futureCapital = new FutureCapitalCalculator()
        .setCapital(BigDecimal.valueOf("10000", MathContext.Decimal_128))
        .setMonthlyExpenses(BigDecimal.valueOf("2000", MathContext.Decimal_128))
        .setMonthlyNetIncome(BigDecimal.valueOf("3000", MathContext.Decimal_128))
        .setNumberOfMonths(300)
        .setYearlyInterestRate(BigDecimal.valueOf("0.04", MathContext.Decimal_128))
        .calculateFutureCapital();
```

It is quite a mouth full, though. We could further better this by moving the creation of the `BigDecimal` into the setters by adding overloads that just accept `String`s. That would shorten the usage to:

```java
BigDecimal futureCapital = new FutureCapitalCalculator()
        .setCapital("10000")
        .setMonthlyExpenses("2000")
        .setMonthlyNetIncome("3000")
        .setNumberOfMonths(300)
        .setYearlyInterestRate("0.04")
        .calculateFutureCapital();
```

Much better. As a further thought, we might rename our setters to `withCapital` or `useCapitalOf`, to have an even cleaner usage API.

```java
BigDecimal futureCapital = new FutureCapitalCalculator()
        .withCapital("10000")
        .withMonthlyExpenses("2000")
        .withMonthlyNetIncome("3000")
        .withNumberOfMonths(300)
        .withYearlyInterestRate("0.04")
        .calculateFutureCapital();
```

The upside is also, that we can reuse a single instance of the class (which, of course, limits the thread-safety).